# Using variables in Power BI Template file (JSON)

Tags: json, powerbi

very simple question, but unfortunately nothing in this regard in the official Power BI Documentation:

I am working with a Power BI Template file (JSON) and would like to use variables for specific color codes ... similar as to working with color codes as variables in CSS, so I only need to change the color code of the variable instead of 5 color values in the template file.

```
"name":"TB Dark Mode 0.1",
    
    "textClasses":{
        "label":{
            "color":"#FFFFFF",
            "fontFace":"Arial",
            "fontSize":9},
    "callout":{
        "color":"#FFFFFF",
        "fontFace":"Arial"},
    "title":{
        "color":"#FFFFFF",
        "fontFace":"Arial",
        "fontSize":10}
```

Instead of changing #FFFFFF three times to something else, I'd prefer having a variable.

```
"name":"TB Dark Mode 0.1",

--font-white = "#FFFFFF",
    
    "textClasses":{
        "label":{
            "color":"--font-white",
            "fontFace":"Arial",
            "fontSize":9},
    "callout":{
        "color":"--font-white",
        "fontFace":"Arial"},
    "title":{
        "color":"--font-white",
        "fontFace":"Arial",
        "fontSize":10}
```

From what I have gathered from JSON documentation, I am not able to create variables ... is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

<s>[Based on this page](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/variables.html#global-variables-example) I think you might be able to do something like the below.  It's valid JSON, but I'm not able to verify if it resolves correctly myself.</s>

Edit: OP said this didn't work for them, but leaving it up for the comment which they did find useful.

```json
{
    "name":"TB Dark Mode 0.1",
    "colorPicker":"#FFFFFF",
    "textClasses":{
        "label":{
            "color":"{colorPicker}",
            "fontFace":"Arial",
            "fontSize":9
        },
        "callout":{
            "color":"{colorPicker}",
            "fontFace":"Arial"
        },
        "title":{
            "color":"{colorPicker}",
            "fontFace":"Arial",
            "fontSize":10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately PowerBI gives an error when trying to import the new template as you described it. "Error Importing Theme File"Thank you though!

Comment: I did find [this Power BI Community Post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Power-BI-full-theme-json-file-example/idc-p/799951/highlight/true#M48700) which links to [an example dark mode template](https://gist.github.com/aaronsteers/5a7f2e454318cc32ea7d0af32c8b710c).  I nearly included it in my answer but didn't as it wasn't directly related.  Any use to you?

Comment: Thanks for the link .. that's a nice additional theme that I might adapt for my needs thank you! Unfortunately still not solving the need for variables in the json template. I fear that this is currently not feasible..